# Loading custom phtml file in static block

Tags: magento2.2, phtml, static-block, magento2.2.3

I have a static block that I want to load a .phtml file from.

I used this code after looking through stackoverflow,

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_page" template="Magento_Theme::html/custompage.phtml"}}
```

My .phtml file is at,

```
/home/website/magento2.com/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custompage.phtml
```

I get a blank white page with no errors in log file, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error was in my .phtml file, it was actually loading the .phtml file but then the .phtml file was causing an error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
{{block class="<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Block\<module_name>" name="<your_block_name>" template="<vendor_name>_<module_name>::<template_directory>/filename.phtml"}}
```

In your case it is look like

```
{{block class="Ashore\Faq\Block\Faq\Index" name="Faq" template="Ashore_Faq::faq/index.phtml"}}
```